# How to detect if keystroke was emulated by keybd_event or SendInput?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard

Is it possible to detect in my custom Win32 control, while processing [WM_CHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx), or [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) message, whether the keystroke came from the *actual keyboard*, or was *emulated* by a call to [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) or [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) type function?

Comment: Technically you can try hooking into `SendInput` or `keybd_event` to intercept them. However it is rather pointless because input can be sent from keyboard device and there is no way to check whether input device is actually real.

Comment: @user7860670, I wonder how forticlient prevents my emulated keystroke by keybd_event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the [`LLKHF_INJECTED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967(v=vs.85).aspx) flag is set in a low-level hook. I don't think you can tell just by looking at the LPARAM.

Comment: Checking for `LLKHF_INJECTED` is indeed the only way to do it. However, there is no *direct* way to correlate low-level hook events with the subsequent higher-level key events that apps will receive after the hook procedure has exited. The hook doesn't even know which app will actually receive the keys, since the hook is invoked after the keystrokes are removed from the hardware queue and before the OS determines the receiving app: [When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773)

Comment: Wow, thank you, both. I didn't know that that flag existed. So to reiterate, to do this I will have to install a global `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook, that has to go into a DLL. And on top of that once I catch that `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag being set in a keystroke there's no way to tell which window it will be dispatched to because that part wasn't done yet by the raw input thread (well, apart from relying on a `GetForegroundWindow` hack).... hmm. Yeah, both of those would be an issue. Why couldn't MS just pass on that flag to WM_KEYDOWN or WM_CHAR. Anyway, just a rhetorical question...

Comment: You don't need a .DLL for the LL hook. If it was easy to detect people would block it for no reason.

Comment: @Anders: Yeah, but wouldn't it be a security concern if input was fed into, say, a password field from an unprivileged running process instead of the physical keyboard?

Comment: That is why the UAC dialog is on a different desktop. Besides, the evil application would have to know the password anyway, brute force is probably too slow using UI automation.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in Windows 8, you can use the [`GetCurrentInputMessageSource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcurrentinputmessagesource) function in your message handler.  You can check if the reported `originId` is `IMO_HARDWARE`, `IMO_INJECTED`, or `IMO_SYSTEM`.