# Detect Zoom-Control in .NET 8 application

Tags: .net, wpf, remote-access, .net-8.0

During remote control in a Zoom meeting, colleagues are causing accidental drag+drop actions in my application (WPF, .NET 8) due to the latency. I now want to deactivate drag+drop in my software in such cases. I have found the following properties for this:

[IsRemoteSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.isremotesession?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[IsRemotelyControlled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.isremotelycontrolled?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0)

However, the properties `IsRemoteSession` and `IsRemotelyControlled` do not work in a Zoom meeting, but apparently only in "real" RDP sessions.

Does anyone know of a way to recognise the control through a Zoom share in a .NET application?

Comment: Instead of trying to detect Zoom, instead check the source of the incoming input window-messages. e.g. here's an unrelated-but-related example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857587/detect-if-wm-mousemove-is-caused-by-touch-pen

Comment: Really good idea. Unfortunately, I can't see from the MouseEventArgs whether it was my mouse or remotely controlled.

Comment: WPF's `MouseEventArgs` type [inherits the `Device` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputeventargs.device?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) which should be different for simulated input from screensharing software vs. local mouse input vs. a touchscreen etc. What do you see if you inspect the `InputDevice` data for `MouseEventArgs` objects from different cursor input sources?

Comment: The `Device` is `System.Windows.Input.Win32MouseDevice` in both cases. And all nested properties of `Win32MouseDevice` look equal.

Comment: Looks like you need to use `GetCurrentInputMessageSource()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72637466/159145

Comment: Awesome, that works! I would never have found that. Will you write it as an answer? Then I can mark it as an accepted answer for others.

Comment: Gladly, - done -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> During remote control in a Zoom meeting, colleagues are causing accidental drag+drop actions in my application (WPF, .NET 8) due to the latency.

I might suggest those kinds of situations would be perfect for a *practical demonstration* of [my favourite kind of ethernet cable](http://www.fiftythree.org/etherkiller/), which should certainly help with the latency issue you've got there.

<sub>Moving on...</sub>

> Does anyone know of a way to recognise the control through a Zoom share in a .NET application?

Well, a *trivial* workaround would be to check `if( System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName( "zoom.exe" ).Any() ) { _ = Process.Start( "shutdown", "/s /t 0" ); }` but that might be a tad *too effective*.

Instead of trying to detect Zoom - which is just one specific modernday annoyance competing with dozens other fungible upstarts today; what you need is a general-solution that can discern simulated input apart from *real* input: I find that most (non-Microsoft/non-Citrix) screensharing and remote-control software will just reach for Win32's `SendInput` blunt-instrument, which, fortunately, makes it easy to detect and ignore.

---

Now, such as it is, WPF's `MouseEventArgs` object extends `InputEventArgs` which exposes an `InputDevice` property, which I initially assumed would indicate if an event came from a physical mouse or another device - or `SendInput` - or whathave you.

...but apparently it isn't as useful as I thought: while it *does* work to differentiate Touch-input from Stylus-input from Mouse-input, it doesn't seem to differentiate between *fake* mouse-input from `SendInput`/`SendMessage`/etc *et al* compared to physical mice, as you discovered.

Fortunately, an alternative solution exists in Win32's `GetCurrentInputMessageSource()`, as some folks [discovered *previously on StackOverflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72637466/159145).

---

The `GetCurrentInputMessageSource( [out] INPUT_MESSAGE_SOURCE* inputMessageSource )` function indicates *exactly* which device or source the last Win32 hWnd window-message received by the current UI thread was from.

...so just call `GetCurrentInputMessageSource` directly and immediately from within your mouse-move or mouse-click or mouse-ate-the-cheese event-handler - and *before* you do anything with `async`/`await` as you need to be calling it from the UI thread.

---

As it's 2024 now, the ol' classic [*forever-trapped-in-the-year-2005*](https://web.archive.org/web/20040609032608/http://www.pinvoke.net/) [website PInvoke.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20220104145751/https://www.pinvoke.net/) appears to have gone-off and joined its contemporary, MySpace, in *the cloud* above - so now we have to use [a new tool from Microsoft called `CsWin32` to generate `extern` functions and `struct` defintitions directly from Windows' header files](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) - so the days of enterprise-grade mission-critical software being heavily dependent on atrocious, VB.NET-only, user-submitted code to pinvoke.net are over.

[Get it from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32).

Anyway, in .NET 4.x, [your import should look like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke-source-generation):

```
[return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
[DllImport( "User32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentInputMessageSource", SetLastError = true )]
static extern Boolean GetCurrentInputMessageSource( ref INPUT_MESSAGE_SOURCE inputMessageSource );

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
struct INPUT_MESSAGE_SOURCE
{
    public INPUT_MESSAGE_DEVICE_TYPE deviceType;
    public INPUT_MESSAGE_ORIGIN_ID   originId;
}

[Flags]
enum INPUT_MESSAGE_DEVICE_TYPE : UInt32 /* DWORD */
{
  IMDT_UNAVAILABLE = 0x00000000,
  IMDT_KEYBOARDv   = 0x00000001,
  IMDT_MOUSE       = 0x00000002,
  IMDT_TOUCH       = 0x00000004,
  IMDT_PEN         = 0x00000008,
  IMDT_TOUCHPAD    = 0x00000010
}

[Flags]
enum INPUT_MESSAGE_ORIGIN_ID : UInt32 /* DWORD */
{
  IMO_UNAVAILABLE  = 0x00000000,
  IMO_HARDWARE     = 0x00000001,
  IMO_INJECTED     = 0x00000002,
  IMO_SYSTEM       = 0x00000004
}
```

In .NET 8, it should be *something like this* (I can't currently test it right now):

```
[return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
[LibraryImport( "User32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentInputMessageSource", SetLastError = true )]
static extern Boolean GetCurrentInputMessageSource( ref INPUT_MESSAGE_SOURCE inputMessageSource );
```